# Distance between clusters kmeans sklearn python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, distance, k-means

I am using sklearn's k-means clustering to cluster my data. Now I want to have the distance between my clusters, but can't find it. I could calculate the distance between each centroid, but wanted to know if there is a function to get it and if there is a way to get the minimum/maximum/average linkage distance between each cluster. My code is very simple:

```
km = KMeans(n_clusters = 5, random_state = 1)
km.fit(X_tfidf )

clusterkm = km.cluster_centers_

clusters = km.labels_.tolist()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're going to have to compute those distances on the cluster centers yourself. Scikit doesn't provide a method for that right out of the box. Here's a comparable problem setup:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
km = KMeans(n_clusters = 5, random_state = 1).fit(X)
```

And how you'd compute the distances:

```
dists = euclidean_distances(km.cluster_centers_)
```

And then to get the stats you're interested in, you'll only want to compute on the upper (or lower) triangular corner of the distance matrix:

```
import numpy as np
tri_dists = dists[np.triu_indices(5, 1)]
max_dist, avg_dist, min_dist = tri_dists.max(), tri_dists.mean(), tri_dists.min()
```

Comment: dists = euclidean_distances(km.cluster_centers_) 
that is what i needed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

km.inertia_ is measure of sklearn’s KMeans is the sum of squared distances.

from the sklearn website:
inertia_: float
Sum of squared distances of samples to their closest cluster center, weighted by the sample weights if provided.
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).